# Обобщенный класс с параметром реализующим несколько интерфейсов

Tags: java, параметры

Создала два интерфейса и хочу создать параметризованный класс, параметр которого является типом этих интерфейсов, но выдается ошибка, что нет такого метода func2() у переменной типа T:

```
class Param<T extends I1, I2> {
    void func(T t) {
        t.func1();
        t.func2(); // ошибка
    }
}

interface I1 {
    void func1();
}

interface I2 {
    void func2();
}
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему так происходит? Как мне правильно параметр типа унаследовать от нескольких типов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильный синтаксис такой:

```
class Param<T extends I1 & I2> {
    void func(T t) {
        t.func1();
        t.func2();
    }
}
```

Только хочу уточнить, что вы используете терминологию немного неправильно. Некорректно говорить, `параметр типа унаследовать от нескольких типов`. Правильней сказать `наложить несколько ограничений на параметр типа`. Т.е. параметр не наследует, мы его для нашего типа ограничиваем, т.е. указываем, какие реальные типы можно использовать в качестве параметра.

Что касается стирания типов (type erasure), то тут ситуация такая. Действительно [согласно спецификации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) при стирании типа используется самое первое ограничение:

> The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound

Но это не означает, что нельзя использовать методы из других интерфейсов. Стирание типов нужно для того, чтоб в скомпилированном коде использовался конкретный тип, так как сама JVM не знает об обобщенных классах.

По сути компилятор трансформирует оригинальный код с обобщенным типом заменяя `T` на `I1` и приводя к `I2` во всех местах, где идет обращение к `I2`. То есть он код превращает в такой:

```
    void func(I1 t) {
        t.func1();
        ((I2)t).func2(); // это приведение можно сделать,
                         // так как компилятор точно знает, что тип t
                         // реализует I2 
    }
```

В чем можно убедиться глянув на скомпилированный код класса:

```
  void func(T);
    descriptor: (LI1;)V
    flags:
    Signature: #19                          // (TT;)V
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_1
         1: checkcast     #20                 // class I2
         4: invokeinterface #22,  1           // InterfaceMethod I2.func2:()V
         9: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 6: 0
        line 7: 9
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      10     0  this   LParam;
            0      10     1     t   LI1;
```

Тут `aload_1` загружает переменную с номером 1 (т.е. `t`), а `checkcast` проверяет можно ли ее привести к `I2`.

Comment: Спасибо!
А еще скажите, пожалуйста, потом параметр Т будет изменен на I1 при стирании типов. 
Почему тогда может вызываться метод func2(), который относится к I2?

Comment: Добавил о стирании типов